# passing a colon as argument of a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, syntax

I would like to know if it's possible to use a **colon ":"** as argument of a function.

Something like that:

```
function  y=func(x)
  if x is a colon
    do this
  else
    do that
  end
```

Also is it possible to pass the key work **end** as argument of a function, and also **1:end**, **3:end-5**, etc...
I doubt it's possible, but I would like to be sure.

Also, I get a weird error when I pass "1:end" as argument of a function, it produces no error, but inside the function, no argument is assigned (not even the other arguments). Do someone know what happens?

Comment: I am not sure you actually need to do this. Tell a bit more what are you trying to achieve. You can certainly pass colon as a string `if x == ":" ...`, **end** can be found by using [size](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/size.html) and passed in as a number.

Comment: Yes, passing it as a string would be a nice workaround.... Good idea.

Comment: That's what happens inside calls to overloaded operator `()`: if you call `x(:)`, the `:` comes in to subsref or subsasgn as the string `':'`. So it seems reasonable. Use `ischar(x) && isequal(x, ':')` instead of `==` though. The `==` will throw errors on size differences, and produce false positives: `==` does implicit type conversion, so `58 == ':'` is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override both for your own classes:

```
classdef MyClass

properties(Access=public)
    data
end

methods
    function out = end(A,k,n)
         disp(A);
         disp(k);
         disp(n);
         out = [];
    end 

    function B = subsref(A,S)            
        disp(S);
        B = [];
    end
end
end
```

As for functions, I never heard of such a functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to pass a colon as an argument (it doesn't make any sense).

Comment: I could give it the sense that I want, if it was possible. It would be some kind of overloading of "argument operator".