# The idea of C array in matlab

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, equivalent, assign

Is it possible to apply the idea of array in C to MATLAB 
For example, if we have
Double array[10];
and if we want to assign a value we write for example
Array[5]=2;

Is there any way to write equivalent one in MATLAB ?

Comment: May the two downvoters explain themselves?

Comment: @Andrey: my guess is that it's because the question is not very clear. What exactly about C-style indexing is OP interested in?

Comment: I mean how to initialise an array and assign a specific value to element in that array in mathlab like what we do in C. I think chris understood what I meant. Thanks for every one gave me his answer or his opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Is it possible to apply the idea of array in C to MATLAB". An array is just a 1D list of numbers (or other data types). MATLAB primarily is designed to work with matrices (MATLAB is short for Matrix laborartory) and an array or vector is simply a special case of a matrix. So I guess the answer to your question is yes, if I have understood correctly.

To initialise arrays or matrices in MATLAB we use [zeros](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/zeros.html) or [ones](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ones.html):

```
>> array = zeros(1,5)

array =

     0     0     0     0     0
```

We can then index elements of the array in the same way as C:

```
>> array(3) = 3

array =

     0     0     3     0     0
```

Note, however, that MATLAB array indexing is one based whereas C arrays are zero based.

[This](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) article describes matrix/array indexing in MATLAB.

Comment: I think that he meant the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own class, override the [] operator.
I described the mechanism in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746547/passing-a-colon-as-argument-of-a-function-in-matlab/8747220#8747220)
Since it is a custom function, you might as well change the 1-based indexing to 0-based indexing.

Regarding the constructor, I doubt that you can do it.

Anyhow, why would you want to do it?
You will confuse all of the Matlab users, and cause havoc.
*When in Rome, do as Romans do.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Arrays are used in C and MATLAB and they can be used for the same functions. Except, please keep in mind the array-indexing of C and MATLAB are different.

The first element of a C array has an index of zero. i.e. in X = [10 20 30 40], x[0] will return 10. But in MATLAB, this will give an error. To access the number 10, you have to use the expression x[1] in MATLAB.

Comment: `x[2]` gives `Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.`

Answer (score 0):

There is no indexing operator `[]`. You must use `()` for indexing array.

If you write

```
x = 1:10;
x[2]
```

then you'll get the following error

```
 x[2]
 |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```